# Unity Asset Bundle

Tags: unity3d

Здравствуйте, хотелось бы узнать, как полностью удалить загруженный Asset Bundle из памяти устройства?

`bundle.Unload(false);` - Выгружает asset Bundle из оперативной памяти

`www.Dispose();`- Освобождает память из веб потока, тоже не совсем понял, что за память в веб потоке...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При загрузке Asset Bundle на устройство, они кэшируются с помощью внутреннего механизма Unity, по-этому удалить загруженный Bundle можно очистив кэш приложения `Caching.CleanCache()`, подробней можно посмотреть [здесь](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/207710103-How-do-I-delete-AssetBundles-from-the-cache-).

Также, если говорить об iOS, то пользователь может удалить все загруженные bundle, очистив данные приложения в настройках устройства.

По поводу `www.Dispose()` - стоит отметить, что наличие метода `Dipose()` у класса `www` намекает на то, что он скорее всего реализует интерфейс `IDisposable` ([почитать о нем можно здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)), который используется для освобождения неупроавляемых ресурсров из памяти, таких как например открытое веб соединие в данном случае, или подключение к базе данных, и вызов `Dispose()` в данном случае используется для закрытие соединения и  (возможно) закрытия каких-либо файлов, в которые писал или которые читал экземпляр класса `www`

Comment: + кроме этого `www.Dispose()` позволяет прервать загрузку, которая сейчас происходит, [вот что про это говорят в Unity3d доках](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.Dispose.html)